# .NET Core Openiddict invalid request

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token, openiddict

im facing a problem trying to implement simple token authentication on .net core 1.0.1, ive followed a simple tutorial that i fond here: 
http://kevinchalet.com/2017/01/30/implementing-simple-token-authentication-in-aspnet-core-with-openiddict/

When i try to send a request to http://localhost:51863/connect/token?grant_type=password&username=alice%40wonderland.com&password=P%40ssw0rd i got the response : invalid_request","error_description":"The specified HTTP method is not valid.

my startup.cs:

```
 services.AddDbContext<AssistDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AssistContext"));
        });
        services.AddScoped<AssistDbContext, AssistDbContext>();

        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        {
            // Configure the context to use an in-memory store.
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase();
            // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
            // Note: use the generic overload if you need
            // to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
        {
            // Register the Entity Framework stores.
            options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<DbContext>();
            // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
            // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
            // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
            options.AddMvcBinders();
            // Enable the token endpoint.
            options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/authorization/token");
            // Enable the password flow.
            options.AllowPasswordFlow();
            // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
            options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
        });

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
           loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
           loggerFactory.AddDebug();

           app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

           app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

           // Register the validation middleware, that is used to decrypt
           // the access tokens and populate the HttpContext.User property.
           app.UseOAuthValidation();
           // Register the OpenIddict middleware.
           app.UseOpenIddict();
           app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        }
```

UPDATE
 Testing with Postman returns 404:

[image]

Logs:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:51863/api/Authorization application/x-www-form-urlencoded 49
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\consultoria.nuget\packages\AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Extensions\1.0.2\lib\netstandard1.4\AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\consultoria.nuget\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities\1.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerMiddleware:Information: The token request was successfully extracted from the HTTP request: {
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "teste",
  "password": "[removed for security reasons]"
}.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\consultoria.nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory\1.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\consultoria.nuget\packages\Remotion.Linq\2.1.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Remotion.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\consultoria.nuget\packages\System.Interactive.Async\3.0.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Interactive.Async.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.1\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.1\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.1\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.1\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred: Method 'get_CurrentTransaction' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTransactionManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.

System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_CurrentTransaction' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTransactionManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.InMemoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.b__2(Int64 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at OpenIddict.OpenIddictProvider`4.<ValidateTokenRequest>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.<HandleRequestAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2017-10-27T14:41:33.6130254Z","tags":{"ai.operation.id":"VBvjL4hwyqs=","ai.user.userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:1.0.0","ai.operation.name":"POST /api/Authorization","ai.device.roleInstance":"CPD200"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"VBvjL4hwyqs=","name":"POST /api/Authorization","startTime":"2017-10-27T14:41:33.6130254+00:00","duration":"00:00:00.4732983","success":false,"responseCode":"404","url":"http://localhost:51863/api/Authorization","httpMethod":"POST","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 490.1896ms 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is extremely clear: you're using a wrong HTTP method (probably GET as I can see the query string parameters attached to the URI).

Use POST as required by the OAuth2 specification and it should work.

Comment: Im using POST now and testing with Postman, he's returning 404, for some reason i cant reach the Exchange function on AuthorizationController

Comment: Are you sure the route associated with the Exchange action is valid?

Comment: Should be, im mapping using  [Route("api/[controller]")] like the rest of my API

Comment: and my method "[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Token(OpenIdConnectRequest request)"
(i change Exchange for Token)

Comment: It's very likely a MVC routing issue. Try with `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` or decorate your `Token` action with `[HttpPost("Token")]`. You can also opt for a root-related route: `[HttpPost("~/api/authorization/token")]`.

Comment: Still the same error, one thing that i notice is when i dont fill any paramter, postman returns the message "error_description": "The mandatory 'username' and/or 'password' parameters are missing." , but if i fill all correctly he returns 404.

Comment: This proves that OpenIddict correctly handles the request and allows MVC to continue processing it (when you don't add the mandatory parameters, OpenIddict directly returns an error). As I said, this is probably a routing issue. Post your logs to confirm it.

Comment: Ive updated the post with the logs, let me know if i do it right.

Comment: Just found the problem, actually i found looking into the logs, only have to remove the line options.UseInMemoryDatabase(); from startup.cs, thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like following Authentication statement is missing from the code snippet

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

Comment: Actually thats for .NET Core 2.x, im using 1.0.1